# How to know the value of a live radio button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a radio button without validation or button.

When the user changes the radio button I want to retrieve the live value.

I have already tried a lot of code but none worked.

```js
var az = document.querySelector("input[name='promotioncases']").checked = true;
console.log(az);

var selectedValue = $("input.promotioncases:checked").val();
console.log(selectedValue);

var selectedRadioValue = $("input.promotioncases:checked").attr("radio-value");
console.log(selectedRadioValue);

const promotion = document.getElementsByName('promotioncases')
for (e of promotion) {
  if (e.checked)
    console.log(`Elément ${e.id} coché`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="black"
  data-target="10"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="10" />
  
<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="red"
  data-target="20"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="20" />

<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="vert"
  data-target="30"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="30" />
```

Comment: [change event (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) gives examples and a caveat for radios

Comment: And in addition to what *freedomn-m* already said, the OP needs to combine that with [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: What do you mean by "without validation or button"? How can you have a radio button without a button?

Comment: `var selectedValue = $("input.promotioncases:checked").val();` should work. Are you running it after the user makes a selection?

Comment: you don't have any `radio-value` attributes, how is that supposed to work? You shouldn't make up your own attributes, that's what `data-XXX` is for.

Comment: the only solution is that of Sandro Jhuliano Cagara

Comment: @pierre ... _"the only solution is that of Sandro Jhuliano Cagara "_ ... actually it represents exactly one possible implementation out of one of many possible approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input[name="promotioncases"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-target'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="black"
  data-target="10"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="10" />
  
<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="red"
  data-target="20"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="20" />

<input
  type="radio"
  name="promotioncases"
  class="promotioncases"
  id="vert"
  data-target="30"
  data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"
  value="30" />
```